# How to create the style as in the attached

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, css3pie

Am beginner with CSS. How can I generate the CSS for generating shadow effect as in the attachment?

[image]

Comment: Use [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) property

Comment: It is most unusual for a brief and unresearched post of this kind to garner two upvotes. If you know of anyone who is "helpfully" upvoting your material as a kindness, please ask them to desist - that is sometimes treated as voting fraud here, and can have serious consequences for account holders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this and you're done...

```
span {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: grey;
    text-shadow: -2px -1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  CUSTOM FRAMING from $99
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(150, 150, 150);
  text-shadow: -2px 0px 2px rgb(150, 150, 150);
  font-size: 30px; /* Optional. Just for demo purposes. */
}
```

**Snippet below:**

```css
p {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(150, 150, 150);
  text-shadow: -2px 0px 2px rgb(150, 150, 150);
  font-size: 30px; /* Optional. Just for demo purposes. */
}
```

```html
<p>
  CUSTOM FRAMING from $99
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text-shadow` property.

Here is an example that gives an inner text shadow.

```
font: bold 200px arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #565656;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
```

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CFW4.png)